# Pandas function which returns all subseries of a window length

Tags: python, pandas

I know that pandas has the function `df.rolling()` where you can do operations on moving windows of subseries. However, is there a function to simply return the subseries instead of a window object in `df.rolling()`?

For example, a series `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` with window length 3 would have subseries `{[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6], [5,6,7], [6,7,8], [7,8,9]}`.

I could do a for loop with N = length of series and m = window length,

```
vectors = np.zeros((N-m+1, m))
for i in range(N-m+1):
            vectors[i] = ts[i:i+m]
```

But it would significantly increase the runtime compared to a built-in function.

Comment: you can check -> https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to write Nk03's comment in an answer here so it's more visible.

The new numpy version 1.20.0 has a function, and I can use

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(ts, window_shape=m)
```

The API page is here: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html

Note that version <1.20.0 do not have this feature.